# How strong are the stellar flares on YZ Ceti?

Tags: fundamental-astronomy, life, flare

Doing research for a game and trying to understand the implications of the stellar flares from [YZ Ceti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YZ_Ceti). In short (ignoring the planets for now), if people were to build large space stations of various types (O'Neil cylinders, hollowed out asteroids, etc.), do the YZ Ceti flares pose a significant danger to them? If so, what would be the frequency and scale of such danger?

Better still, what reliable sources can I consult and how would I interpret them so I can figure this out on my own? I'm getting tired of searching and finding the [Kerbal Space Program forums](https://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/164868-three-planets-for-yz-ceti/).

Comment: I'd start by tracking down all the reference papers listed at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YZ_Ceti  .   You haven't stated whether you're more interested in total insolation effects (energy disaster) or just magnetic & high-energy photon damage.

Comment: Further, given the extremely short orbital periods of planets b,c,d,  I'm betting they are tidally locked, so just put your digs on the dark side of the planets.

Comment: Question is too broad. Fortunately there is an extensive Wikipedia page which it is unnecessary to repeat here. YZ Cet certainly fits into the type of star considered there. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitability_of_red_dwarf_systems